# Cannot read request xml body element value

Tags: xml, go

I cannot seem to ready body element from XML request in my application.

I tried `BodyParameter` from Go-restulf package below but it doesn't seem to work and it just returns nil.

```
// BodyParameter parses the body of the request (once for typically a POST or a PUT) and returns the value of the given name or an error.
func (r *Request) BodyParameter(name string) (string, error) {
    err := r.Request.ParseForm()
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return r.Request.PostFormValue(name), nil
}
```

Below is what I have currently on my file:

```
type Account struct {
    title, firstName, lastName, email, dob, countryCode, addrLevel, addUnitType, addrUnitNo, addrAllotment, addrBuildingNo, addrStreetName, addrStreetType, addrStreet1, addrStreet2, addrCity, countryState, addrPostcode, telephone, mobile string
    userName, password                                                                                                                                                                                                                        string
    currency                                                                                                                                                                                                                                float32
    challenge1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                string
    response1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 string
    AdminUser, AdminPass, Version string
}

func (api *ApiResource) create(request *restful.Request, response *restful.Response) {
    account := &Account{AdminUser: user, AdminPass: pass, Version: version}
    err := request.ReadEntity(account)
    if err != nil {
        response.WriteErrorString(http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(request.BodyParameter("UserName"))
}
```

Is there a reason why this isn't working as expected?

Comment: Can you post an example on the playground? When you say "it doesn't seem to work and it just returns nil", I'm curious what exactly doesn't work and whether the string part of the return value is exactly nil, or if it is an empty string and the error part is not nil.

Comment: @AustinMullins return of `r.Request.PostFormValue(name)` as part of BodyParameter function is somehow returning nil. I am using custom package so I'm unable to post this example sorry

Comment: @PassionateDeveloper The PostFormValue method cannot return nil. Perhaps you mean the empty string. The PostFormValue method returns the empty string if there is no value with the given key or if the request body is not a form. It sounds like the request body might be XML, not a form.

Answer (score 0):

All your struct variables are not exported except `AdminUser, AdminPass, Version`.

From http://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers:

> An identifier may be exported to permit access to it from another
>   package. An identifier is exported if both:
>
> 1. the first character of the identifier's name is a Unicode upper case
>      letter (Unicode class "Lu"); and
> 2. the identifier is declared in the
>      package block or it is a field name or method name.
>
> All other identifiers are not exported.